# how to seprate null value and real value in ios

Tags: ios

"",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "\"22.6926798\",",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "\"22.6925942\",",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "\"22.6879868\",",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "\"22.6862004\"",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""

all "" is empty. how to seprate and store another nsmutablearry in real value

Comment: you should check with nil value in condition like if value != "" { append value in array }

Comment: empty string? What's that? CSV? What's your current code? Objective-C or Swift ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **Swift 3.0** .

```
func excludingEmptyString(_ strings : [String]) -> [String]
    {
        var new = [String]()
        for each in strings
        {
            if each.characters.count > 0
            {
                new.append(each)
            }
        }
        return new
    }
```

and call `func excludingEmptyString()` like this

```
let strings = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "\"22.6926798\",", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "\"22.6925942\",", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "\"22.6879868\",", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "\"22.6862004\"", "", "", "", "" ]

print(excludingEmptyString(strings))
```